# uilabel inside a uiview -- adding gesture to the label not owrking

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a uilabel (and other labels as well) inside a uiview.
I added a gesture that when the label is tapped on I perform some ibaction.

The action is not triggered, however if i place the label outside the uiview (meanning it's not a child of the uiview) than it works fine. I placed it back inside the view than it's stop triggering the action.

any idea why?

something when the label is inside the uiview makes it not react to the gesture and I'm not sure why (despite the fact that both the uiview and the label have 'User interaction enabled).

TIA

Comment: You added the label inside UIView or UIImageView?
Also please post some code

Comment: Why not add a transparent custom button over the label to get this to work? (assuming single tap)

Comment: Makes sure `userInteractionEnabled` is set to `YES` on the containing view

Comment: [self.lbltst setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.resultView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.resultView action:@selector(dispDetail)];
    [self.lbltst  addGestureRecognizer:tap];
Above is the code -- the label is lbltst and the uiview that contain the label is resultview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently there was an issue with the parent control, I redrew the View and it worked fine. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Or just not have a UILabel and have only the text of the button be visible, that way you dont have to have a UILabel and a UIButton (from a memory perspective).

Comment: I don't like the idea of a label and on top of it a button, and there is really no need since I can hook the label to trigger event using gestures. The only problem is that it works is the label is not inside another container, in that case UIview.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that the `UILabel` is receiving the touch event instead of the UIView.  Try adding the following code (modified to fit your label, of course) to the `viewDidLoad` method:

`myLabel.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;`

This should allow touch events to pass through to the UIView.  Why are you doing this?  Might it not be easier to work with a `UIButton`?

Comment: I want the uilabel gesture to work not the uiview but it's once it's inside a uiview it's not.